# How to get a partilcular item from a Dictionary object with index?

Tags: c#

How to retrive an item from an dictionary object using an Index? eg i have a dicitiory object of 10 items and i have to get the 5th keypairvalue from the dictionary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dictionaries are unordered. If you mean "the 5th item added to the dictionary" - they don't provide this functionality.

One thing to be careful of is that in many cases `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` *appears* to be ordered - if you just add a bunch of entries and then iterate, then under the current implementation I believe you will at least *usually* get back the pairs in the same order. However, it's not guaranteed, it's not *meant* to happen particularly - it's just a quirk of the implementation. If you delete entries and then add more, then the whole thing goes pear-shaped.

Fundamentally, if you want ordering as well as key lookups, you need to store a list as well as a dictionary.

Comment: Thnx. I am reading your c# in depth and it was amazing.. do you have any new releases related c#4.0.

What about the ElementAt method, if the order of the dictionary is defined and sometime i couldn't able to get the key, is it a gud idea use that method?

Comment: What does the shape of a pear have to do with the order of dictionary entries?

Comment: @Kishore: Glad you're enjoying it. Yes, I'm working on the second edition now - it should be out soon. See http://manning.com/skeet2. If you use `ElementAt` you will get *an* entry (assuming you pass in a valid index), but there's no guarantee which entry it will be.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using .NET 3.5 or greater:

`var keyValuePair = d.ElementAt(4);`

However, this is using an enumerator behind the scenes and the ordering of enumerated items from a dictionary is not guaranteed:

> The IDictionary interface allows the contained keys and values to be enumerated, but it does not imply any particular sort order [(From IDictionary reference on MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea(v=VS.80).aspx).

This means that the element you get back might not correspond to the order you inserted it in and thus is probably not what you expect.

There is an [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) class in `System.Collections.Specialized` that enforces the ordering and allows you to access by index through the Item indexer.  However, this is from the pre-generics days so it only accepts `object` key-values and thus isn't quite as friendly to work with as the generic collections.

I just found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/GenericOrderedDictionary.aspx) on CodeProject that implements a generic OrderedDictionary.  I have never used this but it might be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fundamental abuse of a dictionary that this question presents:

```
int counter = 0;
foreach (var pair in yourDictionary)
{
    if (++counter == 5)
    {
        // pair contains your fifth item
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a generic dictionary like this:

```
Dicionary<int,string> myDict = new Dictionary<int,string>();
```

You could pull the 5th value from the dictionary by converting the output to a list:

```
string SomeString = myDict.Values.ToList()[4];
```

But typically you'd use a dictionary when you're more concerned about retrieving a value based on a pre-determined key rather than it's position in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The 5th according to which ordering? The `Dictionary` class does not guarantee any specific ordering. If you want it in some specific ordering, retrieve the pairs from the collection (for example as *John* suggests) and sort them, then get the `KeyValuePair` at the index you need. If you need it ordered by insertion order, try using the `System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary` instead, then you can access the `KeyValuePair` directly by index.

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Linq

string item=dicOBj.Keys.ElementAt(index);

you can get both key and value in the same way specifying index

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework has 8 dictionary classes: Dictionary, Hastable, ListDictionary, OrderedDictionary, SortedDictionary , SortedList, SortedList Generic. In all these classes items can be retrieved by key, but items can be retrieved by index only in OrderedDictionary, SortedList, SortedList Generic. If you need to retrieve from you dictionary items by key or by index you must use one of these classes: OrderedDictionary, SortedList, SortedList Generic.
How to use these classes you can find: [OrderedDictionary Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) , [SortedList Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)